# Rails - convert String from a user form to Array in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a model that uses tags which I'm trying to serialize in the database, as seen below.

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :tags, Array
...
end
```

My form has the following-

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :tags %>
  </div>
```

And my controller-

```
def create
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
```

But when I click submit to create the Trip, I get the following error-

**Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "Asia, China"**

Is there someway to have Rails automatically convert that string into an array? I tried doing it manually in the model using a `before_validation` call, but I still got the same error. I feel like there's an easy way to do this I'm unaware of...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
@trip = Trip.new(trip_params.except(:tags))
@trip.tags = trip_params[:tags].split(",")
@trip.save!
```

Comment: Could also be improved by making sure `tags` comes in as an array, like naming the field `tags[]` in the HTML.

Comment: @tadman Good advice. In that case, it needs to have more than `1` text fields... But OP is taking all values in the same text_box as a comma separated.

Comment: True. I think things like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) can help make that easier.